# background image with overlapping content depending on mobile or desktop view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Running into a layout issue between mobile/tablet and desktop.

For mobile: I need the hero image to be first, then the content to be beneath it. ([sample here](http://cl.ly/image/2P1F0J0U0i0f))

For tablet/desktop: I need the content to lay *on top* of the hero image. ([sample here](http://cl.ly/image/3s0z2z2t073W))

I've tried using a background image but found that adjusting the layout of the page effects the background image size and proportions

I've tried absolutely position one on top of the other but run into a scenario where I end up fiddling with the layout between views (using bootstrap) more than what should probably be manageable.

Would love any thoughts on how to produce this result.

Will try to provide code samples of what I've done but not sure it's relevant since none of it seems to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example that I've created for you, please check:

```css
#container {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
#image, #content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#image img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #image, #content {
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div><div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. Lorem ipsum dolor ismet. </div>
```

Click on `Run Code Snippet` and view the above snippet in `Full Page` and then reduce your browser window to `500px` or smaller, you'll see that the content will automatically get under the image. Initially, both the `<div>` containing the image and the content are being displayed as `inline-block` but for screens smaller than 500px, we use `@media-queries` to change their `display` property to `block` which is why the content goes underneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

When width of window will be less, than your tablet/desktop content, switch media query and just display your divs block. For displaying them in row use `display:inline-block;`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v0jcmqav/). Try to resize result window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CodePen example I set up to accomplish what you're asking: http://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/pyCnf

Essentially, if you use an inline image as compared to a background image, you can set it's `position` to `absolute` at a certain media query breakpoint. With it's container positioned `relative` and the image's sibling (`.hero-content`) positioned `relative`, you can just float it right at that same breakpoint, change the width to however wide you want it, and it sits right on top of the image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero-contain">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/300/" class="hero-img">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In a enim eu risus accumsan venenatis. Donec venenatis nunc ac tellus tempor, ac rutrum lorem semper. Suspendisse pulvinar elit sed luctus pulvinar. Donec id ultricies dui. Pellentesque suscipit nulla maximus, mollis urna laoreet, tempor tortor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero-contain {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.hero-img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hero-content {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .hero-img {
    position: absolute;
  }

  .hero-content {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```